# CSS Contain input text to 100% width

Tags: html, css

So when I set the input like this example the text box, because it has a border and padding by default, will be wider than 200px.

```
<div style="width:200px; background-color:red;">
    <input type="text" name="fname" style="width:100%;"/>
</div>
```

I know I can force the text box to fit within the 200px by setting a class to the input tag and tagging it with this CSS

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Is there a better way to get this text box to size correctly, i.e. to fill 100% as I want it to do? I cannot use fixed sizes. I am using CSS themes so the text box padding, margins, etc are not known at compile time. They can be changed out by the user on the fly. So the solution must work regardless of what the text box's padding, border, and margin is.

Comment: I think border-box is really the only way to go. You could use javascript, but this CSS declaration is far more elegant.

Comment: Yeah I know you can do it in Jquery pretty easily, but I agree I would rather keep it all in CSS.

Comment: @mrtsherman it can be done pure css without `box-sizing`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think you have already answered your own question. `box-sizing: border-box;` is really the only CSS means of getting the element to fit inside its parent. css-tricks goes into great detail about this here.

http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

I am unaware of any other CSS you could use other than using javascript to perform some calculations and then modifying your input elements.

Comment: Thanks I think you are right. It just seemed like there must have been a better way and I wanted a second opinion.

Comment: @VladimirStarkov - your example is pretty confusing. Can you modify this base case to showcase how it works? Please don't add any additional demo only styling like border-radius, box-shadow, etc. Looking forward to the explanation. http://jsfiddle.net/peFFW/1/

Comment: @mrtsherman  what exactly is not clear explained? [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/matmuchrapna/peFFW/2/) may be helpful.

Comment: @VladimirStarkov - thanks, that helps clarify what you are doing.

Answer (score 6):

#### *Yes.* You **can do** it.

You can do it without using `box-sizing` and *not clear* solutions like `width~=99%`.
[**Demo on jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/matmuchrapna/uaKZn/1/):
[image]

**HTML markup:**

```
<div class="input_wrap">
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
    padding: 6px 17px; /* equal to negative input's margin for mimic normal `div` box-sizing */
}

input {
    width: 100%; /* force to expand to container's width */ 
    border: 7px solid #DFDFDF;  
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin: 0 -17px; /* negative margin = border-width + horizontal padding */ 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<div style="width:200px; background-color:red;">
    <input type="text" name="fname" style="width:100%;border:1px;padding:4px;margin:-5px"/>
</div>
```

Comment: He doesn't know the input's border/padding/etc because they are generated by a theme. So he can't set explicit values to force it in place.

Comment: the idea is make margin(minus)=padding+border, to let it cancel out. When width is 100%

Comment: I see. So to use this solution would require javascript then because you would have to calculate the negative margin offset and apply it. Seems sound.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div style="width:200px; height:22px; background-color:red;">
    <input type="text" name="fname" style="width:97%;margin-left:1%;"/>
</div>
```

?

But seriously, though, here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rockerest/rmzyN/).

Comment: He doesn't know the input's border/padding/etc because they are generated by a theme. So he can't set explicit values to force it in place. He could have an input with `padding: 100px` and because padding is added to width it would cause the input to overfill the parent.